# CiviCRM on Wordpress - Suppressing 'Administer' Menu items

Tags: wordpress, permissions, menu

Top Menu  --> "Administer"
I'd like to suppress **ALL** the menu items like "Administration Console" through "System Settings" but **allow** all the other menu items like :

- Civi Campaign
- Civi Case
- Civi Report
- Civi Discount

Thanks.

Comment: Are you looking to hide these from everyone including Administrators or only users with specific roles?

Comment: I'm creating a couple of roles. Admins get everything.. WordPress, all civi, etc. Sub- admins will get all privs in civi, but will not be able to create users or install plugins. Then a third group that won't be able to create custom fields, or create relationship types or relationships, but can create membership types...

Answer (score 1):

Some of the menus will change based on the permissions you set for each user role in WordPress Access Control under 'Administer>User and Permissions>Permissions (access control)'

Then under 'Administer>Customize Data and Screens>Navigation Menu' you can set permissions for each menu item by right clicking on the item and selecting edit.

You should be able to get the menus setup for each role as you need them. May take a bit to tweak it.

Hope this helps.